# Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse identity

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

I came across the following:

Let $n \leq m$, $L \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, with $\operatorname{Ker} L=\{0\}$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.

Denote by $L^{\dagger}$ the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $L$, and $\Pi_F$ is the orthogonal projector onto $F$.
We know that $L^{\dagger}=\left(L^{\top} L\right)^{-1} L^{\top}$.

I read  $D L^{\dagger}(A)=-L^{\dagger} A L^{\dagger}+\left(L^{\top} L\right)^{-1} A^{\top} \Pi_{(\mathrm{Im} L)^{\perp}}$, but there is no mention of $D$. I suspect that $D$ might be a diagonal matrix.

Does this identity (or a corrected version of it) ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: So $n\le m$?.... And do you mean $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$?

Comment: If you assume that $m=n$ and $A = I$, then the equality reads $DL^{-1} = -(L^{-1})^2+(L^TL)^{-1}P_{(\text{im}L)^\perp}$ and so $D = -L^{-1}$. Just saying...

Comment: @amsmath yes $n \leq m$, I edited.

Comment: "I came across the following" Came across where?

Comment: While reading a math problem (obviously badly written).

Comment: Is $D$ some kind of derivative? As in the exterior differential or something like that?

Comment: The reason I think so is because, if $LL^{-1} = I$, then $dLL^{-1} + L d(L^{-1}) = 0$, so that $d(L^{-1}) = -L^{-1} dL L^{-1}$, which is close to the first term. I assumed you had an invertible matrix. This is probably a generalization of what I wrote for Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverses. Good luck.

Comment: Continuing my series of comments, I think $D$ is a directional derivative.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks @Malkoun

Comment: Yes, it seems like a differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $D$ signifies derivative. Let $M$ be an invertible matrix. Since $M^{-1}=\operatorname{adj}(M)/\det(M)$ is a rational function in the entries of $M$, $DM^{-1}$ exists when $M^{-1}$ exists. As
\begin{aligned}
(M+H)(M+H)^{-1}-I
&=(M+H)\left(M^{-1}+DM^{-1}(H)+O(\|H\|^2)\right)-I\\
&=MDM^{-1}(H) + HM^{-1} + O(\|H\|^2)
\end{aligned}
we get $DM^{-1}(H)=-M^{-1}HM^{-1}$ and hence
$$
(M+H)^{-1}=M^{-1}-M^{-1}HM^{-1}+O(\|H\|^2).
$$

Similarly, $L^+=(L^TL)^{-1}L^T$ is a rational function in the entries of $L$. So, it is differentiable whenever it exists. Now, suppose $A$ is a small perturbation to $L$. Then
$$
(L+A)^T(L+A)=\underbrace{L^TL}_M+\underbrace{L^TA+A^TL+O(\|A\|^2)}_H=M+H.
$$
It follows that
\begin{aligned}
&\left[(L+A)^T(L+A)\right]^{-1}(L+A)^T-(L^TL)^{-1}L^T\\
=&(M+H)^{-1}(L+A)^T-M^{-1}L^T\\
=&\left(M^{-1}-M^{-1}HM^{-1}+O(\|H\|^2)\right)(L+A)^T-M^{-1}L^T\\
=&\left(M^{-1}-M^{-1}HM^{-1}+O(\|A\|^2)\right)(L+A)^T-M^{-1}L^T\\
=&M^{-1}A^T-M^{-1}HM^{-1}L^T+O(\|A\|^2)\\
=&M^{-1}A^T-M^{-1}\left(L^TA+A^TL+O(\|A\|^2)\right)M^{-1}L^T+O(\|A\|^2)\\
=&-M^{-1}L^TAM^{-1}L^T+M^{-1}A^T(I-LM^{-1}L^T)+O(\|A\|^2)\\
=&-L^+AL^+ + (L^TL)^{-1}A^T(I-LL^+)+O(\|A\|^2).
\end{aligned}
Therefore $DL^+(A)=-L^+AL^+ + (L^TL)^{-1}A^T\Pi_{(\operatorname{Im} L)^{\perp}}$.